# std::make_tuple and rvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++11

Like below, why "vv" here is not an rvalue-reference? Here the type of "v" is rvalue-reference, and according to the inference rule of `decltype`, the `decltype` of an rvalue-reference (not a prvalue) should be the type of rvalue-reference, right?

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int x{};
  const auto [v] = std::make_tuple<int&&>(std::move(x));  // v -> const int &&;
  decltype(v) vv = 10;  // vv -> const int;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Happens because `std::make_tuple<int&&>` returns `std::tuple<int>`. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple):

```
template<class... Types>
tuple<VTypes...> make_tuple( Types&&... args );
```

> For each `Ti` in **`Types...`**, the corresponding type `Vi` in **`VTypes...`** is
> `std::decay<Ti>::type` unless application of `std::decay` results in
> `std::reference_wrapper<X>` for some type `X`, in which case the deduced
> type is `X&`.

If you use `std::tuple` instead of `std::make_tuple` -- it works as you expect it to.

Here is [code to play](https://godbolt.org/z/MThP68).